# How to save an email attachment to file

Tags: delphi, base64, email-attachments, indy10

I would to save an email attachment to a file using a TIdImap4 object of Indy Ver.10.

I get the UID of the email, then I use this code:

```
lMsg := TIdMessage.Create(Self);
lImap.UIDRetrieveStructure(lUid, lMsg);
lMsg.MessageParts.CountParts;
if lMsg.MessageParts.AttachmentCount > 0 then
  for lJ := 0 to lMsg.MessageParts.Count - 1 do
    if (lMsg.MessageParts[lJ] is TIdAttachment) and
       SameText(lMsg.MessageParts[lJ].Name, 'MyAttachment') then
      lImap.UidRetrievePartToFile(lUid, lJ, lDimAllegato, lFileName, Trim(lMsg.MessageParts[lJ].ContentTransfer))
```

This worked until `lMsg.MessageParts[lJ].ContentType = 'Text/Plain'` and 
`lMsg.MessageParts[lJ].ContentTransfer = '7bit'`, now `UidRetrievePartToFile()` returns False and no file is created. I suppose because
`lMsg.MessageParts[lJ].ContentType = 'application/octet-stream'` and
`lMsg.MessageParts[lJ].ContentTransfer = 'base64'`.

I'm not skilled on this topic, what I need to change in code in order to save this type of attachment?

I also tried with: `TIdAttachment(lMsg.MessageParts[lJ]).SaveToFile(lFileName)`
and similar, but the file created was always empty.

Answer (score 3):

Using `UIDRetrieveStructure()` with a `TIdMessage` is going to fill the `TIdMessage.MessageParts` with a lot of `TIdttachment` objects, never any `TIdText` objects, and not all of the objects are going to represent actual attachments.  You are using the `TIdAttachment` indexes as the `APartNum` parameter of `UIDRetrievePartToFile()`, which might not be accurate.

And you can't use `TIdAttachment.SaveToFile()` when using `UIDRetreiveStructure()`, because no actual data has been downloaded, only the structure of the email, which then allows you to download the data for the specific elements you want.

I suggest you use the other overloaded version of `UIDRetrieveStructure()` that fills a `TIdImapMessageParts` instead.  Amongst other things, `TIdImapMessagePart` gives you an exact `ImapPartNumber` that you can then give to `UIDRetrievePartToFile()` (as well as the `ContentTransferEncoding`):

```
lParts := TIdImapMessageParts.Create(nil);
try
  lImap.UIDRetrieveStructure(lUid, lParts);
  for lJ := 0 to lParts.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if (lParts[lJ] is the desired attachment) then
    begin
      lImap.UidRetrievePartToFile(lUid, lParts[lJ].ImapPartNumber, lDimAllegato, lFileName, lParts[lJ].ContentTransferEncoding);
    end;
  end;
finally
  lParts.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Just lParams[lJ].ImapPartNumber is lParts[lJ].ImapPartNumber